# Setting environment variable before program name

Tags: environment-variables

I have come across commands like this:

```
CC=gcc ./configure
```

What is the effect  of it exactly?

Is it identical with

```
export CC=gcc

./configure
```

?

Does the variable `CC` continue to exist after `configure` is finished?

Answer (score 1):

The first example sets the variable for that one command alone. The second sets it for all subsequent commands run from that shell.